# slice [] from a result of Object.key

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object in javascript and i want just the key of this object I do:

```js
let key = Object.keys(compilerequest.resultMetadata)
```

it returns something like `["effective date"]` and I wanna slice this key and return it like `"effective date"` when I'm trying `key. map (s=>s. slice (1,15))` it returns `["ffectivedate"]`, how can I slice the []?

Comment: how can i slice the []

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! you can edit your question by pressing the edit button :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let key = Object. keys (compilerequest. resultMetadata) // returns ["effective date"]
```

Then

```
let [key] = Object. keys (compilerequest. resultMetadata);
console.log(key) // returns "effective date"
```

This is called destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Thank you! can you mark the answer as accepted please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers